# Jewish American word for stuffed cabbage

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, food

The word used by non-American and many American Jews for stuffed cabbage is 'holishkes'. There are a few variations.

But I heard someone use a word that sounds like 'hole-up-tious'.  I cheched numerous spellings such as *holupzes, cholupzes*, etc., but could not find anything.

I am assuming it is an American word used only in English because this family have been in the US for over eight generations (originally from Russia — but it is not a Russian-Jewish word).

Has anyone ever heard it before? There was one reference that looked similar in sound but it was quite obscure. I am wondering whether this is a regional word from a small group of Jews in NY, or perhaps just a family word.

Answer (score 3):

The word is "holiptshes". [This article](http://forward.com/articles/13845/philadelphia-prakas-/) gives a lot of the etymological background.